# What's wrong to replace the subclass constructor with super(objects)?

Tags: java

```
public abstract class MyAbstractList<E> implements MyList<E> {
    protected int size = 0; // The size of the list

    /** Create a default list */
    protected MyAbstractList() {
    }

    /** Create a list from an array of objects */
    protected MyAbstractList(E[] objects) {
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
        add(objects[i]);
    } 
}

public class MyArrayList<E> extends MyAbstractList<E> {

     public static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;
     private E[] data = (E[]) new Object[INITIAL_CAPACITY];

     /** Create a default list */
     public MyArrayList() {
     }

     /** Create a list from an array of objects */
     public MyArrayList(E[] objects) {
         for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
             add(objects[i]); // Warning: don't use super(objects)!
     }
}
```

The implementation of the second constructor in MyArrayList is the same as for MyAbstractList,
What is wrong if lines 11–12 in MyArrayList.java,

```
for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
    add(objects[i]);
```

are replaced by

```
super(objects);
```

or

```
data = objects;
size = objects.length;
```

Comment: I don't understand what do yo you want to do with your "or" possibility

Comment: To understand your problem entirely, we need the code of the MyList's interface and the add's methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*MyArrayList.data* is not initialized yet by the time the constructor of *MyAbstractList* would run if called as `super(objects)` from the *MyArrayList* constructor

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation.  You're right, just remind me to review the initialization block problem.  In summarized, Instance initialization block (IIB) code are executed when the class is initialized and before constructors are invoked. and the compiler executes parents class’s IIB before executing current class’s IIBs.

Answer (score 1):

I try to fill in the blank and I don't see why your IDE say that.

In mine (IntelliJ IDEA), there's absolutely no error at all.

Comment: IDE will not report any compile errors, but if you run the code, it will crash in *MyArrayList.add* because it will be called from the *MyAbstractList* ctor before the *MyArrayList.data* field is initialized

Comment: Yes, I ran it with no error reported, too.  That's what have frustrated me.  And here, @MBobrik explained the problem. Thank you both for solving my frustration.